# SimpleSaveWriteStore in dojo - how to read elements

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, dojo

new to dojo and javascript in general. I'm working with a piece of code that requires a button to be different depending on what a php database query returns. The php script is already written, and the code I have currently is:

```
var store = new SimpleSaveWriteStore( {url: "info_get.php"} );
```

info_get.php returns the data as a JSON object, but what is the syntax to access the data members inside store? I've searched for this but there isn't a whole lot of documentation I've found on SimpleSaveWriteStore.

TL;DR - how would I access a specific piece of data retrieved in the above code? Thanks!

Comment: If you can post the json returned from the php script, I can give more direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleSaveWriteStore` isn't a part of Dojo, so I am going to assume that this is this where you got the code from:

http://kennethfranqueiro.com/2010/06/custom-save-logic-itemfilewritestore/

This code extends the `dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore`, and you can query against the store.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#query-syntax

A couple things to note.  Dojo is moving toward `dojo.store` api instead of the `dojo.data` api (which is the the ItemFileRead and ItemFileWrite store).  The dojo store api documentation can be found at:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/store.html

Also, if the data that you are getting back from the php script, is very simple, a store might not even be needed.  You could use `dojo.xhr` to make the request and get json data.  Then just use the json data to get the value that you need.  The data and the store api use `dojo.xhr` to get the data. The documentation for `dojo.xhrGet` can be found at

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/xhrGet.html

Comment: thanks, `SimpleSaveWriteStore` turns out to be a custom function that the previous programmer defined.. took me a while to find it.